# Error deleting the last UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following code to populate my tableview:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (friendsArray.count > 0)
    {
        return friendsArray.count;
    }
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    if (friendsArray.count <= 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"It is lonely here";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Please add some friends";
    }
    else
    {
        Friend *friend = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = friend.name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = friend.email;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        FriendDelete *friendDelete = [FriendDelete new];
        friendDelete.FDDelegate = self;
        Friend *friend = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [friendDelete deleteFriend:friend.requestId];
        [app showLoader:@"Deleting.."];
    }
}
```

And for deleting the friend on delegate call I have written:

```
- (void)friendDeleteSuccessfull:(NSString *)userId
{
    [app hideLoader];
    [app dispToast:@"Deleted Friend"];
    for (Friend *friend in friendsArray)
    {
        if ([friend.userId isEqualToString:userId])
        {
            NSInteger row = [friendsArray indexOfObject:friend];
            [friendsArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];
            [friendListTable endUpdates];
            [friendListTable reloadData];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works all fine until I reach the last row. When I try to delete the last row of the table, the app crashes with the following error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318/UITableView.m:1582
```

So changed the code so that the `endUpdates` is called only if the array has any values, else call the `reloadData` directly by adding the following condition:

```
if (friendsArray.count > 0) {
   [friendListTable endUpdates];
}
```

Now there is no crash on the last row deletion, but the table still shows the last row. That is, the table is not getting reloaded at all. What can be the possible issue. How can I solve it?

Comment: You need to provide the full assertion error message. There should be another sentence or two describing the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: Do you ever set the data source to friendsListTable?

Comment: Can you explain the logic in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` ? Why not just return count of friendsArray

Comment: try to remove the line `[friendListTable endUpdates];`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write `[tableView reloadData]` in

```
if(friendsArray.count > 0){
    [friendListTable endUpdates];
    [tableView_object reloadData];
}
```